# Why are these integrals equivalent to the Riemann Hypothesis?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, riemann-hypothesis

Riemann Hypothesis is equivalent to the integral equation

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\log \mid \zeta (1/2+it)\mid }{1+4t^2} \ dt =0$$

Many other integral equations exist that are equivalent.

How to show that they are equivalent ?

They usually include absolute value of a function.

Why is that ?

I assume it came from a contour integral on the riemann sphere.

The growth rate of the zeta function on the critical line also probably relates to all those integrals , not ?

Another example is

Establishing the exact value
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{(1-12t^2)}{(1+4t^2)^3}\int_{1/2}^{\infty}\log|\zeta(\sigma+it)|~d\sigma ~dt=\frac{\pi(3-\gamma)}{32}$$
is equivalent to the Riemann Hypothesis.

More examples :

Riemann's Hypothesis is true if and only if
$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\infty} \log\left|\frac{\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+it)}{\zeta(\frac{1}{2})}\right|\ \frac{dt}{t^2}=\frac{\pi}{8}+\frac{\gamma}{4}+\frac{\log 8\pi}{4}-2$$

Take $a\in R$ with $\frac{1}{2}\leq a<1$. Riemann's $\zeta$-function has no zeros in $\Re(s)>a$ if and only if
$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\infty} \log\left|\frac{\zeta(a+it)}{\zeta(a)}\right|\ \frac{dt}{t^2}=\frac{\zeta'(a)}{2\zeta(a)}-\frac{1}{1-a}$$

And many more exist.

I have no idea how to get to such conclusions or prove them.

Im not even sure how to prove integrals for "slightly easier" cases , meaning not famous open problems but zero's of other nontrivial functions that are not on a half-plane.

Comment: Note that $\log|z|=\mathrm{Re}(\log(z))$

Comment: The first equivalence is due to balazard and saias (original proof comes from Jensen applied to a transform of zeta using the mobius map that bends the critical line into the unit circle and sends the right half plane to the interior; bui and others gave a proof using cauchy and basic rz estimates; very popular topic here on mse; for the more general integral  equivalences, will strongly recommend broughan's tomes on the subject, especially  volume 2

Comment: As a heuristic $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\log \mid \zeta (1/2+it)\mid }{1+4t^2} \ dt \ge 0$ (for example because in Jensen formula the extra terms that come from zeroes is always non-negative), while the integral is most negative precisely around the critical line zeroes, so it makes sense that the integral will be minimal when there are the most possible critical line zeroes which is RH

Comment: I suspect that a solution to those integrals will involve a sum over the Riemann zeta zeros.

Comment: Let the numbers 4 and 3 be replaced by infinity, and you might have a starting point for approximating the integral: `Integrate[Log[Sum[(E^(Round[Log[n]*4]/4))^(x), {n, 1, 3}]],x]` in [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BLog%5BSum%5B%28E%5E%28Round%5BLog%5Bn%5D*4%5D%2F4%29%29%5E%28x%29%2C+%7Bn%2C+1%2C+3%7D%5D%5D%2Cx%5D) And modify the integral approximation to include analytic continuation of the Riemann zeta function. See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4216806/8530