Solution to integral $\int \frac{1}{x-x \, \text{cot}(x)+1} \, dx$
As per title, I am looking for the solution of the integral involving the trigonometric cot function.
The problem comes from a differential equation that I derived for a time-dependent variable $x\equiv x(t)$,
\begin{equation}
x' = 2 B_1 x - \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k \frac{2^{2k}B_{2k}}{(2k)!} x^{2k}
=
x - x \, \text{cot}(x) + 1,
\end{equation}
where $B_j$ are Bernoulli numbers, $B_1=1/2$ and we used the connection to the series expansion of cot.
Proceeding with the separation of variables we obtain
\begin{equation}
 \int \frac{1}{x-x \, \text{cot}(x)+1} \, dx = \int dt= t+ C,
\end{equation}
Similarly, if we consider $B_1=-1/2$ (the first Bernoulli number can be either positive or negative) we obtain (up to a global minus sign) the slightly different variant of the LHS, namely,
\begin{equation}
 \int \frac{1}{x+x \, \text{cot}(x)-1} \, dx  .
\end{equation}
Online calculators have not been helpful and no valid approach to tackle the integrals comes to my mind. Is at least one of these two integrals solvable?
edit: what I find surprising is that substituting cot with coth Wolfram outputs an explicit solution:
\begin{equation}
\int \frac{1}{x-x \, \text{coth}(x)+1} \, dx = 1/2 [x + \log(x \, \text{cosh}(x) - (1 + x)\, \text{sinh}(x))]+C
\end{equation}
Can this somehow help? (considering $\text{coth}(x) = i \text{cot}(ix)$)

What's the source of this integral?

The integrands can be written in terms of one another. Reciprocals of a mix of trigonometric and non-trigonometric functions seem to have no closed form, but maybe substituting $y=x+x\cot(x)-1$ and solving for $x$ as a series/integral would help/

Adding 3 elements in the denominator can be tricky for an integrand. The integral might not even be expressible by standard functions.  See : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612879/integral-int-1-infty-fracdx12x3x
and that is not even an indefinite integral.
Nevertheless I will try to solve this one ...

I see two close votes. perhaps add some source or motivation. I like it and upvoted btw.

Not an answer but the similar looking $\int (1 +  \cot(x))^{-1} dx = 1/2(x-  \ln(\sin(x) + \cos(x)))$ might help. Maybe the functional inverse of $x + x\cot(x)$ or $x + x\cot(x) -1$ could be part of the solution.  Just thinking out loud

If I am not mistaken Ramanujan considered the functional inverse Tyma and I have mentioned. But I was not able to find a reference.

@mick I have edited my question with some more context. Although, the problem is about the integral... I am not very familiar with integrals and "functional inverse", could you please elaborate a bit?

@Gwen I added some more context, in short it comes from a differential equation involving  aBernoulli numbers series that imply the cot function.

@EmFed I think your last integral is indeed the key to the solution !

Im not sure if this is solvable but the edit shows hope , effort , context and motivation. I already upvoted and now I voted to reopen and I suggest others to do the same !

@mick thanks a lot for championing the reopening of my question :) So you think that the integral with the hyperbolic function coth can shed light? It is true that coth(x)= i cot(ix), but I cannot see a clear way through...

I don't understand the idea of writing $\coth(x)$ as $i \cot (ix)$, I would rather go for the $e^x$-related definition and get an $e^x$ behind the $d$ ($d e^x$).

This might help? $$\frac12\int\frac{(x\sin x-x\cos x+\sin x)+(x\cos x+x\sin x+\sin x)-2x\sin x}{x\sin x-x\cos x+\sin x}\mathrm dx$$

@MathGuy I imagine that the integral you wrote is related to my problem, but I cannot clearly identify the direct connection? Also, I tried to feed your input into some online integral calculators: apparently this doesn't have a closed form solution either...

Using this relation and multivalued product log function $W_k(z)$ with $x=\operatorname{Im}(W(t))$ gives the integral as $\frac{i-1}2\int \frac{d(W_{-1}(t)-W(t))}{W(t)+iW_{-1}(t)+1+i},t<-\frac1e$

The integral can be written in terms of $\int\frac {dx}{1-\cot(x)+\frac1x}$ and there is a fairly complex expansion for the inverse of $\frac1x-\cot(x)$, but it would give a triple sum solution to the integral. Is this answer wanted?

nice question ........... +1

@ТymaGaidash indeed, I currently Taylor-expand the inverse of the denominator and then integrate the terms individually. This gives a good approximation, but I was hoping that we can find an exact, closed form solution...
