Integral $\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt[4]{\ln(1+t)} +\sqrt {\ln(1+t)}}{t^2+1} dt$
Consider
$$ I = \int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt[4]{\ln(1+t)} +\sqrt {\ln(1+t)}}{t^2+1} dt$$
Find a closed form for $I$ and show that $I > 1$.
We know that
$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(x+1)}{x^2+1} \mathrm dx = \frac{\ln(2) \pi}{8}$$
For instance by these 2 proofs :
Consider:
$$I(a) = \int_0^1 \frac{\ln (1+ax)}{1+x^2} \, dx$$
than, the derivative $I'$ is equal:
$$I'(a) = \int_0^1 \frac{x}{(1+ax)(1+x^2)} \, dx = \frac{2 a \arctan x - 2\ln (1+a x) + \ln (1+x^2)}{2(1+a^2)} \Big|_0^1\\
= \frac{\pi a + 2 \ln 2}{4(1+a^2)} - \frac{\ln (1+a)}{1+a^2}$$
Hence:
$$I(1) = \int_0^1 \left(  \frac{\pi a + 2 \ln 2}{4(1+a^2)} - \frac{\ln (1+a)}{1+a^2} \right) \, da \\
2 I(1) = \int_0^1 \frac{\pi a + 2 \ln 2}{4(1+a^2)} \, da = \frac{\pi}{4} \ln 2$$
Divide both sides by $2$ and you're done.
Or this proof
Put $x = \tan\theta$, then your integral transforms to $$I= \int_{0}^{\pi/4} \ln(1+\tan\theta) \ d\theta. \tag{1}$$
Now using the property that $$\int_{0}^{a} f(x) \ dx = \int_{0}^{a} f(a-x) \ dx,$$ we have $$I = \int_{0}^{\pi/4} \ln\biggl(1+\tan\Bigl(\frac{\pi}{4}-\theta\Bigr)\biggr) \ d\theta = \int_{0}^{\pi/4} \ln\biggl(\frac{2}{1+\tan\theta} \biggr) \ d\theta.\tag{2}$$
Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get $$2I = \int_{0}^{\pi/4} \ln(2) \ d\theta\Rightarrow I= \ln(2) \cdot \frac{\pi}{8}.$$
Or this proof
$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln (x+1)}{x^2+1}dx=\int_1^0\frac{\ln\frac{2}{1+t}}{\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)^2+1}\cdot\left\{-\frac{2}{(1+t)^2}\right\}dt =\int_0^1\frac{\ln 2-\ln (1+t)}{t^2+1}\ dt.$$
and with some trivial algebra you get the solution.
Similarly we can compute the easier integral :
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt {\ln(1 + t)}}{t + 1} dt = 2/3 \ln^{3/2}(2)$$
or this one
$$ \int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt {\ln(1 + t)}}{\sqrt {t + 1}} dt = 2 \sqrt{\ln(4)} - \sqrt {2 \pi} \space erfi(\sqrt {\ln(2)/2}) $$
and many similar ones.
We also have
$$\int \sqrt {\ln(1+x)} dx = (x+1)\sqrt {\ln(1+x)} - 1/2 \sqrt \pi \space erfi(\sqrt {\ln(1+x)}) + C.$$
$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt {\ln(1+x)}} = \sqrt \pi \space erfi(\sqrt {\ln(1+x)}) + C.$$
and there is also a long closed form for
$$\int \ln(1+x) \sqrt {1+x^2} dx $$
or a slighly less long closed form for
$$\int \frac{\ln(1+x)}{\sqrt {1+x^2}} dx $$
I am not sure that the indefinite $\int \frac{\sqrt[4]{\ln(1+t)} +\sqrt {\ln(1+t)}}{t^2+1} dt$ can be solved by standard functions.
But the definite integral with range $\int_0^1$ seems more likely to have a closed form.
Maybe some contour integral is helpful.
Or a series expansion for say $\sqrt{\ln(1+x)}$.
Lagrange inversion might help.
Or the more general Lagrange–Bürmann formula:
see
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem
Faa di Bruno might also help
see
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula
see also the related Gregory coefficients :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregory_coefficients
In fact $\frac{1}{ln(1+x)}$ has been studied alot, and even its generalization $\ln(1+x)^t$ but I was not able to find free sources.
They are often called "generalized " Gregory or Bernouilli coefficients and they satisfy many properties.

Why do you believe the integral has a closed form?

@PrincessEev I think I answered that in the question already. Many similar integrands have a closed form, many even for the indefinite integral. And they do not even use very special functions. The integrand is not a long expression and it does not have many compositions or sums in the denominator ( such as this one https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612879/integral-int-1-infty-fracdx12x3x ) , so it should be solvable by some functions with high probability. Series expansions of $\ln(1+x)^y$ have been extensively studied such as the gregory coefficients and related.

I think substitions with $t = t +1$ and $t = \exp(t)$ work ... after those series expansions.
